# Scanning database table, looking for NULL values in any column and if found, storing only that column in array

Tags: java, arrays, database, web

I'm trying this but got stuck. This piece of code will scan the table from database (data is of VARCHAR type). It will look one column at a time. If it finds null in a column, it'll store that column entries in an array. The problem is that values are not storing in array. Its output is a blank page. (It's actually a java web application). Kindly give any suggestions.

```
for(int k = 1; k < totalColumns; k++)   // k = column number
{
    int i = 0;
    innerwhile:
    while(result.next())
    {
        String value = result.getString(k);
        if(value.equals("null"))
        {
            result.beforeFirst();

            while(result.next())    // storing column in array
            {

                String tempValue = result.getString(k);
                if(tempValue.equals("null"))
                {
                   ; // do nothing because in array I don't need null values                       
                }
                else
                {          
                    rowValues[i] = tempValue;
                    i++;
                }

            }
            i = 0;

            break innerwhile;
        } // end if
    } // end labeled while

    result.beforeFirst();                
}
```

Comment: do you really have the string "null" in your db and not a null value?
Unrelated: instead of if(something){//do nothing}else{//do something} use if(!something){//do something}

Comment: Currently in database, there are 4 columns of type VARCHAR and 3rd column has a string "null" in the 7th row. So I suppose this code will store 3rd row in the array, but it's not

Comment: it would be helpfull if you would add how you obtain result and provide a Minimal, Comlete and Verifyable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve